# What Puranas cover the stories of Ganesh Chaturdhi Puja

Tags: puranas, ganesha, festivals

On Ganesh Chaturdhi, Puja called Varasidhi Vinayaka Vrat is performed. In the Vrat, the following stories are told.

1. Story regarding birth of Vinayaka and his head being replaced with that of Elephant.
2. Story of Ganesha cursing Moon for laughing at him
3. Wives of Rishis facing Neelapaninda When Swaaha devi took the form of Rishi patnis to please Agni Deva
4. Syamantaka Mani story of Krishna due to looking at moon on Ganesh Chaturdhi day

What are the Puranic origins of these stories? Which Puranas (and which chapters) mention these stories. And Which purana contains the procedure and Tithi of Ganesh chaturdhi Puja ?

Also, it is a practice that whoever saw moon on Ganesh Chaturdhi should recite the following sloka.

सिंहः प्रसेनमवधीत्सिंहो जाम्बवता हतः। 
सुकुमारक मारोदीस्तव ह्येष स्यमन्तकः॥

What is the origin of this belief and which Purana has this?

Kindly help please.

Comment: I think Varaha Purana has the details.

Comment: I don't know about the story of Ganesha Chaturthi Vrata, but the sloka you have quoted occurs in the Harivamsa, 1st Parva, 38th Chapter 36th Sloka, during the story of Syamantaka Jewel.

Comment: @Rickross Are all the four stories in Varaha Purana? Can you point out the chapters?

Comment: @Rickross and @ Student [This chapter](http://www.indianscriptures.com/scriptures/puranas-18-puranas-mahapurana/the-varaha-purana/vol-i/chapter-23/topic-1) of Varaha Purana talks about Ganesha's birth and as you can see it is not the popular version. :)